# Closing the child form of the child will cause an error in the parent form

Tags: c#, wpf

Main form

```
private void menuEquipPreference_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EquipPreferenceForm form = new EquipPreferenceForm();
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Child form

```
editForm.ShowDialog();
if (editForm.DialogResult.HasValue && editForm.DialogResult.Value)// 닫을시 getinfo 실행
{
    GetInfo();
}
```

Child's child form

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }
```

The command to reload the grid via getinfo.

But I get an error in mainwindow: System.NullReferenceException

edit

call stack first parent and second grand parent

why call stack twice?

---

Showdialog the doubletab on the mainform and showdialog another popup in the doubletab's window, and dialogresult calls both the doubletab's window and the mainform's showdialog. So I think a null exception error occurs

Comment: Different language, but the general idea is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024099/how-to-troubleshoot-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
if (editForm.DialogResult.HasValue && (bool) editForm.DialogResult.Value ?? false)
```

Comment: dialogresult to bool? Type doesn't go in Is there a namespace you should use?

Comment: DialogResult?.HasValue   red line
bool does not contain a definition for Hasvalue